# defer with current value

Tags: go

I would like to call the function using defer with the most current values of parameters in the function's arguments.
I suspected that running this code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    s := "ABC"
    
    defer fmt.Println(s)
    s = "DEF"
}
```

I will get **DEF**. But that what I get is **ABC**. Is there any way to get **DEF**?

Comment: ["The deferred call's arguments are evaluated immediately"](https://tour.golang.org/flowcontrol/12)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a closure around the variable you want to capture:

https://play.golang.org/p/W4xt_KSOJNj

```
s := "ABC"

defer func() {
    fmt.Println(s)
}()
s = "DEF"
```

Comment: …or pass a pointer to the variable into a deferred call—in that case the pointer's value will be evaluated when preparing the arguments for a deferred call, and the call itself will use that evaluated address to access the variable's content. In this toy example [you will need a closure anyway—as you can't force functions of `fmt` to dereference pointers](https://play.golang.org/p/FWkAiElCcKe), but in a general case, when you control the function to be called, this may work in a more understandable way, IMO.